# ByteArrayOutputStream Writing to File In Log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I have the below code which do serialisation and save the output in the file. I also want to write this in log4j log file what's the correct way to do it ?

```
private ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    public void writeToFile(){
    
        try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filePath, true)) {
                 baos.writeTo(fileOut);
                 this.baos.flush();
                 log.info(baos.toByteArray())   // Is this correct will it give me the same out put as above line ?             
 
        }catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.error("Error while writing query: ", e);
                }
     }
```

Comment: If that byte array contains a serialized object, there is no point in logging it, as the bytes will be unreadable by humans.  You might as well just log the number of bytes it contains.

Comment: @VGR we writing it to some file via logger also, which we use later  so I want to check will  it will be same as `baos.flush()`

Comment: And what is the point?  What are you hoping to see in the log that could help someone?

Comment: @VGR this log file will contain data which is used by other services

Comment: And suppose your log has `711a000001bd494441544889635cedbe8781968089a6a68f5a306ac1d0b0808578a5dc129c1226c29c22ec5f5ffeb8bf` in it.  *How is that useful?*

Comment: @VGR as I said we are not using it will send the data to other service which consume this they will have the  doserializer at their end

Comment: The reason we are doing this so we can get rid of file write as it's not thread safe and log4j will take care of the threadinging so only thing I want to know how to write `baos.writeTo(fileOut);` to logger

Comment: Ah, I see.  You mean that the log file itself will be directly used by other services.  You are essentially using log output as a form of communication.  In that case, there are probably better ways to accomplish your task.  Logging binary data will require transforming it to text in some way (such as hex digits as in my example), and the receiving end will need to reverse that transformation.  You would be better off implementing your own thread safety with synchronization or a Lock, and writing your data directly as bytes, like you’re currently doing.

Comment: @VGR `log.info(baos.toByteArray()) `  and `this.baos.flush();` will do the same thing i.e content would  be the same I want make sure this.
`baos.toString()` would be different ?